# Azure ML Studio Execute Python Script Error - No module named 'azure.cognitiveservices'

Tags: python, azure, ml-studio

I'm getting below error in Azure ML Studio while running 'Execute Python Script'
Error - No module named 'azure.cognitiveservices'

its really strange why it can't find azure inside azure?

However the same python script works fine when I run it through Jupyter Notebook

Answer (score 1):

The Execute Python Script contains pre-installed packages mentioned in this [list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/algorithm-module-reference/execute-python-script#preinstalled-python-packages).

So in your case the cognitive services is not included - hence the error.

You can install the package by including the below code

```
import os
os.system(f"pip install <Packagename>")
```